# Sort an array based on values from another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which i would like to sort it based on values from another one.
FIrst array:

```
$array1 = ( '2' , [val]->'3' , [val1]->'1')
```

And second one:

```
 $array2 = (1,4,3)
```

I've tried a bubble sort but does not work:

```
  for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $array1[0] ; $i++){
    for ($j = $i+1 ; $j <= $array1[0] ; $j++){
        if ($array2[$i] < $array2[$j]){
            $temp = $array1[$i];
            $array1[$i] = $array1[$j];
            $array1[$j] = $temp;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_multisort` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @verisimilitude it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `usort()`, it allowes you to give user defined function to sort..

[Documentation..](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)